# How to create Named form builder to use few forms in one request Symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, symfony

How to create Named form builder to use few forms in one request Symfony 3

```
$registration_form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->setMethod('POST')
                ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('id' => 'reg_username', 'class' => 'form-control', 'autocomplete' => 'off')))
                ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
                    'type' => PasswordType::class,
                    'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                    'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')),
                    'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password'),
                    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
                    'required' => true,
                ))
                ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary', 'style' => 'margin-top:15px;margin:bottom:15px')))
                ->getForm();
```

**I have found some example for symfony 2 and i need something simiar for symfony 3:**

```
// build form
        $formBuilderOne = $this->container
                ->get('form.factory')
                ->createNamedBuilder('formOne', 'form', NULL, array('validation_groups' => array()))
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('submit', 'submit');

        // get form from form builder
        $formOne = $formBuilderOne
                ->getForm()
                ->handleRequest($request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function multiformAction()
{
    $form1 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($formTypeA, 'form1name')
        ->add('foo', 'text')
        ->getForm();

    $form2 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($formTypeB, 'form2name')
        ->add('bar', 'text')
        ->getForm();

    if('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {

        if ($request->request->has('form1name') {
            // handle the first form
        }

        if ($request->request->has('form2name') {
            // handle the second form
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form1' => $form1->createView(),
        'form2' => $form2->createView()
    );  
}
```